# connect to oracle database which located on other ip using R

Tags: r, database, oracle

I need connect to oracle database via R
I do so

```
library(RODBC)
library(RJDBC)

odbcConnect(dsn = "NBD-TEST-DEV-BLACKBOX", 
            uid = "Y", pwd = "X")
```

i use oracle sql developer client to get access

When i try connect via R
i get the errors
Warning messages:

```
1: In RODBC :: odbcDriverConnect ("DSN = NBD-TEST-DEV-BLACKBOX; UID = x; PWD = y"):
   [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Data source not found and no default driver used
2: In RODBC :: odbcDriverConnect ("DSN = NBD-TEST-DEV-BLACKBOX; UID = x; PWD = y"):
   ODBC connection failed
```

i think it becase the database on another IP (R on server which ip x.x.x.x, and oracle on IP Y.y.y.y

So i have two questions
how can i indicate path to ODBC , where it. My oracle sql developer in path `"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sqldeveloper-19.1.0.094.2042-x64"`

and how to indicate needed IP when connect

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so, I think you'd normally set up a DSN in the windows ODBC interface first, test connection, all that... then access that in R

Comment: @cory, via oracle sql developer i easy get access to my base, i can get data from base to csv and then load in R, but i want  get from R

Comment: Google how to set up an odbc connection in windows and do it. Then you can use that connection from R.